# Clicking links with the middle mouse button in Python3/Qt6

Tags: pyqt6, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage

I used a Python3 script under GTK, where I clicked on a link with the left mouse button to open it in the same window and on a middle mouse button to open it in a separate window.

I am now in the process of migrating this script from GTK to Qt6.

The problem is that I cannot intercept the middle mouse button in conjunction with a clicked link:

My browser window is based on `QWebEngineView`, I can intercept mouse button clicks with an event filter (`eventFilter()`), and I can intercept clicked links within the `acceptNavigationRequest()` function of a `QWebEnginePage`.

The URL of the clicked link is only available in `acceptNavigationRequest()`, but this function is only called by Qt6 when I use the left mouse button, not, as desired, the middle mouse button (neither does control + left mouse button work).

How can I let a middle mouse button click be recognized in a navigation request?

---

Debian 11.6 Bullseye, Python 3.9.2, PyQt6-Qt6              6.4.1

Comment: Are you trying to handle new window requests?

Comment: No. I want acceptNavigationRequest() be called, when I click a link with the "middle" mouse button, instead of normally the "left" one.

Comment: By default, middle clicks in browsers open the link in a new tab/window. You can intercept this by overriding [`createWindow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebengineview.html#createWindow), and just returning the same view (`return self`), which will automatically call `acceptNavigationRequest()` right after that.

Comment: Excellent. You might wish to copy your comment to an answer, so that I can accept it. Thanks 

Comment: That wouldn't be a completely appropriate answer: `createWindow()` also happens when clicking on a link that has a different `target`.

Comment: Well, I do not know, what you mean with a "different target" and what problem could arise, but your solution solved my problem and would therefore qualify for an "accepted answer". So, if you feel uncomfortable with technically providing an "answer", I would do the job by myself, otherwise people would think that my problem is not solved 

Comment: Web pages can ask to open a link in another tab/window (for instance, `<a href="..." target="_blank">`), and `createWindow()` will be called also in that case, so with that basic approach there is absolutely no way to tell the difference between a link clicked with the middle button or one that tries to open a new window even when using the left button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Window does not open new window or tab on external url link click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472415/window-does-not-open-new-window-or-tab-on-external-url-link-click)

Comment: After reading again your question, I now realize that you're simply trying to mimic the common behavior of browsers (I was under the impression that you needed to get the `acceptNavigationRequest()` in the *same* instance). If that's the case, please accept the duplicate proposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @musicamante (note the comments in the original post), I solved my problem this way:

```
g_mouse_button = '--'

class MyWebEngineView(QWebEngineView):

  def __init__(self):
    ...

class MyEventFilter(QObject):

  def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    global g_mouse_button
    ...
    if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.MiddleButton:
      g_mouse_button = 'middle'
     ...
    ...

class MyWebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):

  def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, ttype, isMainFrame):
    global g_mouse_button

    if  ttype           == QWebEnginePage.NavigationType.NavigationTypeLinkClicked and \
        g_mouse_button  == 'middle':
      <open link in new window>
      g_mouse_button = '--'
      return False # ignore

    return True # process

  def createWindow(self, window_type):

    return self

if __name__ == "__main__":
  ...
  event_filter = MyEventFilter()
  g_app.installEventFilter(event_filter)
  ...
```